# Questions on Néron–Severi group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles, neron-severi-group

$\DeclareMathOperator\NS{NS}\DeclareMathOperator\Pic{Pic}$I have two questions on a comment from Daniel Hyubrechts's [Complex Geometry](https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf) on pages 133/134.

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Consider the exponential sequence on cohomology

$$ \dotsb \to H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)=\Pic(X) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \to \dotsb$$

> *Remark 3.3.3* Often, the image of the map $c_1:\Pic(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{R}) \subset H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is called the *Néron—Severi group* $\NS(X)$ of the manifold $X$. It spans a finite dimensional real vector space $\NS(X)_{\mathbb{R}}= \NS(X) \otimes \mathbb{R} \subset  H^2(X,\mathbb{R}) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$, where the inclusion is strict in general. The Lefschetz theorem above thus says that the
>   natural inclusion $\NS(X) \subset H^{1,1}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ is an equality.
>
> If $X$ is projective, yet another description of the Néron–Severi group can be
>   given. Then, $\NS(X)$ is the quotient of $\Pic(X)$ by the subgroup of numerically
>   trivial line bundles. A line bundle $L$ is called numerically trivial if $L$ is of
>   degree zero on any curve $C \subset X$.

Q_1: Why in case of $X$ projective i.e. closed subscheme of projective space, these two descriptions of *Néron—Severi group* coincide? Thus why the image of $\Pic(X) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{R})\subset H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ coincides with quotient $\Pic(X)/A$ with $A$ subgroup of numerically trivial line bundles?

Remark: during my search I found this  [old MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583320/neron-severi-group-as-the-image-of-first-chern-class) where the OP faced a similar problem but the given answer not satisfies me contentually and in the mentioned reference Griffiths–Harris' Principles of Algebraic Geometry I also not found an explanation on the proof.

Let me explain that more precise: in the answer it is claimed that the kernel of $c_1$ consists exactly of line bundles that are algebraically equivalent to $0$. These are $L \in \Pic(X)$ such that we find a variety $T$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a line bundle $\tilde{L}$ over $X \times T$ with $L \vert _{t_1 \times X} =L$ and $L \vert _{t_2 \times X} \cong O_X$. The subgroup containing such $L$'s is also called $\Pic^0 X\subset \Pic X$. 
None of these two claims were proved or sketched what is going on these identifications. In summary we have two subgroups of $\Pic(X)$:

1) the numerical trivial line bundles (defined in Remark 3.3.3). Other name: *numerically* equivalent to zero

2) $\Pic^0(X)$: it's possible to find a variety $T$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a line bundle $\tilde{L}$ over $X \times T$ with $\tilde{L} \vert _{t_1 \times X} =L$ and $\tilde{L} \vert _{t_2 \times X} \cong O_X$

That is the motivation of the question is to understand why in case of $X$ projective the kernel of $c_1$ coinsides with 1) & 2).

Q_2: Why is the map canonical map $H^2(X,\mathbb{R})\subset H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ induced from the inclusion $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$ of the local constant sheaves injective?

Comment: Q_1 is answered in Lazarsfeld's book "Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I", see Remarks 1.1.20 and 1.1.21.

Comment: Q_1 is not correct. For instance for an Enriques surface $S$, the canonical bundle $K_S$ is numerically trivial but not trivial, while $\operatorname{Pic}^{\mathrm{o}}(S) =0$.